# OClint warning confusion for C

Tags: c, oclint

I have a program with the following line of code in it

```
if (counter % 2 == 1){
```

and OClint is giving me the warning "broken oddness check", which from the documentation states that it won't work for negative numbers, which I understand, but the solutions it gave me was to use

```
if (counter % 2 != 0){
```

which then gives me an "inverted logic warning" and tells me to use the first code again... I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do here. Thanks!

Comment: How about `if (counter % 2)` ?

Comment: Solved! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Comment: That second warning is kind of dumb in this case. Yes, inverting logic is often less than desirable, but it's still better than the non-explicit option of neglecting to mention what exactly you're testing equality against.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I agree. I think some might consider it more readable than the "accepted" solution.

Comment: Another option would be to use an unsigned integer type for `counter` — how often do you need a negative count?

Comment: @jonathan: That depends on what you're counting. If it is mistakes, then you do need a negative count :)